# how to install pip from whl file

Tags: python, pip

I have a file called:

```
pip-19.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

I unzipped this and this resulted in the following 2 directories:

```
pip
pip-19.2.2.dist-info
```

I read on other answers that you locate the setup.py file and run

```
python setup.py install
```

But I cant locate the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wheel directly like this:

```
python3 ./pip-19.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install ./pip-19.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score -1):

**How to install pip on windows**

1> Download get-pip.py to a folder on your computer.

2> Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder containing get-pip.py.

3> Run the following command:

```
python get-pip.py
```

You can verify that Pip was installed correctly by opening a command prompt and entering the following command:

```
**pip -v**
**pip -help**
```

**How to install pip on Linux**

For Ubuntu System using below command:

```
apt-get install pip
```

For Cent OS System using below command:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install python-pip
```

Comment: ive tried this and it diesnt work before due to connection/proxy issues