# How do I install pip from a .whl file

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I want to install pip from "*pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl*",  I would use pip to decompress and install a .whl file.

**How else can I do it?**

There are two ways (which of I know of) to install pip.

1. Install with the Python installer exe.
2. Download and call "get-pip.py".

I have tried and failed both, as they are not achievable with my following conditions.

- I cannot use the Python installer exe because it does not contain required content (such as folders PC or PCBuild).
- "get-pip.py" returns an error about zlib not available
- there is a Proxy PAC file used to configure the internet traffic, which prohibits automation of downloading packages.

**get-pip.py Error**

```
D:\Python\Python-3.7.6>python get-pip.py
Running Debug|Win32 interpreter...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 23484, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Just download a pip source package here https://pypi.org/project/pip/ , then unzip the source package, then copy-paste `pip-20.1.1/src/pip` to `D:\Python\Python-3.7.6\Lib\site-packages`, then run `D:\Python\Python-3.7.6>python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip` to do other steps. But, anyway, I think maybe the last step will be failed, because the copy of Python you installed may be incomplete

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried this and as you suspect it doesn't work. I get an error saying that there's no module named '_socket' `File "D:\Python\Python-3.7.6\lib\socket.py", line 49, 
  in <module>  import _socket
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to install pip from whl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215195/how-to-install-pip-from-whl-file)

Comment: Following the answer from [how to install pip from whl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215195/how-to-install-pip-from-whl-file) I got an error saying `ImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available` so I unpacked the whl file and tried `python pip install` which results with the same  error as before `No module named '_socket'`

Comment: socket is a built-in module, so you should consider re-install your python. where did you get your python installation? it must be a bad site.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your Python installation. Some parts of the standard library seem to be missing or malfunctioning. I would recommend reinstalling Python from scratch. (Are you by chance using the "_embeddable zip file_"? If yes, then that might be your problem. It is not a complete Python, parts are missing.)